# Better organize AngularJS model-service code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coding-style, angular-services

I'm trying to develop a "model" service to keep my shared data synchronized between my controllers.
I ended up with this solution:

```
myApp.factory('UserService', function() {
  return {
    data: {
      user: {
        vm: {
          firstName: '',
          lastName: ''
        },
        save: function() {
            console.log("save user");
        }
      },
      settings: {
        vm: {
          theme: '',
          language: '',
          currency: ''
        },
        save: function() {
            console.log("save user settings");
        }
      },
      save: function() {
        console.log("save all");
      }
    }
  };
});
```

(fiddle here to better understand how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/n36kpuf6/).

I don't think it's a bad solution, it keeps my HTML tidy and I can see at the glance what functions I can use in my controllers, keeping them slim; I prefer it among other solutions of data-sharing based on events or $scope...

At the same time I'm thinking that, maybe, it's a bit confused; so I was searching trough the John Papa styleguide how I can keep it better organized, but I can't find examples about this kind of "model" services, just simple services based on methods... so I ended up thinking that I miss something.

Can someone please give me advices on how I can keep this service better organized?

Comment: *"maybe, it's a bit confused"* ...why? Controllers should be lean and services should have as much of the business logic as possible.

Comment: well.. I have model and functions in the same structure; if my functions were filled with "real" code they would become long and the whole structure not so readable.

Comment: Write the functions as named functions below the object and just pass function references then to your `data` object

Comment: yeah... I was thinking the same thing... anything else anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Why putting function inside of your object? Why don't you retrieve just a clean object :

```
myApp.factory('UserService', function() {
  return {
    data: {
      user: {
          firstName: '',
          lastName: ''
      },
      settings: {
          theme: '',
          language: '',
          currency: ''
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: because whenever I inherit the service in the controller I get the model itself and its functions to play with.
for example... I get the user data and its function to save it to the backend.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this solution:

```
myApp.factory('UserService', function() {
  var service = {
      user: {
        vm: {},
        save: saveUser
      },
      settings: {
        vm: {},
        save: saveSettings
      },
      save: saveAll
  };

  return service;

  function saveUser() {
    console.log("save user");
    console.log(service.user.vm);
  }

  function saveSettings() {
    console.log("save user settings");
    console.log(service.settings.vm);
  }

  function saveAll() {
    console.log("save all");
    console.log(service);
  }
});
```

(fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/tudev0xc/)

I think it remains versatile and readable.